Upgrade to 24.04 did not appear in software updater
I have several Ubuntu X86-64 LTS machines that I maintain.  All were 22.04 current.  I migrated one to 24.04 (actually, 24.04.1 after the upgrade release was made available), and Software Updater displayed that the upgrade was available. On the second machine that in terms of OS and sysadmin is identical (different end-user applications, none systems), despite having an up-to-date 22.04, the upgrade to 24.04 was not offered.  I had to use a terminal CLI to invoke the manual commands and the machine is downloading the full files (in a terminal, not GUI, window).  Environment is stock 22.04 (to stock 24.04) under MATE as the end-user GUI -- but not MATE Ubuntu Linux.  All of the settings in Software Updater were the same, including notification of the availability to upgrade to the next LTS release.  But, that upgrade was never offered on the second machine.  Any idea why?

I think you have some mix up in version info in your question. Please read it over and correct as needed.

Thank you catching that "typo".   I currently am download the Ubuntu 24.04.1 ISO install image that I shall place upon a USB stick and make bootable.  I shall shutdown and boot my machine from the USB stick.  Assuming this works, I should be able to do the upgrade to 24.04.1 from the bootable USB stick.  Note that neither machine has different partitions for /home, /opt/, /usr/local as I have done in the past, but the default partitioning from the "modern" Ubuntu installs.  On my machine (success), these non-system "directories" were untouched.  To be continued.

Continuation.  Assuming that the failed upgrade machine does boot from the Ubuntu 24.04 install USB, will the upgrade allow these non-system directories (/home/, /opt/, /usr/local/) be left untouched?  These no longer are actual partitions visible under, say, GParted.  Is there a method using the installation USB to guarantee (by manual intervention during the upgrade process if necessary) to leave these untouched?

For ordinary updates through apt (or equivalent GUI systems like KDE's Discover), Ubuntu now has a Phased Update policy. Updates to important packages are gradually released to larger and larger numbers of systems in the hope that any remaining bugs are caught before they affect too many users (AskUbuntu explanation).
It's possible that the phased update policy is also being applied to full distro upgrades (e.g. 22.04 to 24.04), since the same logic applies, and it would be consistent without your observations. I have read claims to that effect from unreliable sources (e.g. Reddit).
However, I could not find any official statement from Canonical confirming this is their policy. And none of the packages listed on the SRU Phased Update List have any mention of 24.04 Noble Numbat in their changelogs, nor in the changelogs of the packages that were updated on the day that I was first offered the upgrade, so if there is a phased update process, it doesn't appear that the offer of an upgrade is made through the normal updates. So there is no reliable evidence for the existence of a phased updates policy for upgrades.

This sounds like you're guessing.

I thought I knew the answer to this, but when I went to get sources to support it, I realized that there wasn't actually any evidence and I was probably wrong. This is very, very far from a perfect answer, but it might be useful information to OP, who asks for "any idea why?". I tried to edit it down to a comment, but couldn't do that without omitting caveats that made it seem more confident, not less. So I think the best course of action is that I post and you downvote.
